# How can I link some device (given by its device ID) with an specific firmware in linux?

Tags: linux, firmware, rules, udev

Imagine I have a new device which it's not working on Linux. I get its device ID with `lsusb`:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID`**`1164:7efd`**`YUAN High-Tech Development Co., Ltd`

Imagine I know that this device will work with this firmware `/lib/firmware/dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw`

Then I would like to create a rule or something that could tell the operating system that the device `1164:7efd` must be loaded with the firmware `dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw`

I just want to link the device ID with the firmware, so my device will work. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have this file:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
```

with this content:

```
# do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update

# firmware-class requests, copies files into the kernel
SUBSYSTEM=="firmware", ACTION=="add", RUN+="firmware --firmware=$env{FIRMWARE} --devpath=$env{DEVPATH}"
```

See examples from rules.d directories in either /lib/udev/rules.d or /etc/udev/rules.d and place your custom udev rules to

```
 /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

At least these are the file locations on a ubuntu server.

My quick guess is that the line should be something like this, but I'm too cross-eyed to look any documents in more detail.

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", SUBSYSTEM=="firmware", ACTION=="add", RUN+="firmware --firmware=/lib/firmware/dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw --devpath=$env{DEVPATH}"
```

see `man udev` for more information.